# Xcode Validation Error : Invalid Bundle OS Type Code

Tags: iphone, xcode

I updated my Xcode to 5.1 and I tried to submit one of my App but looks lots of things have been changed. When I tried to validate my App before submitting, then I got this error

[image: validation error]

but for when clicked on distribution, I have this error

[image: distribution error]

How can I resolve it and submit my App to APP Store ?

Comment: What does your Info.plist file look like? What's the value for the `CFBundlePackageType` key?

Comment: Here is that:

<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>BNDL</string>

I also tried APPL (which was there as default).

Answer (score -1):

1. Check  your targets.
2. Check Info.plist  CFBundlePackageType 
   APPL
3. Check Bundle Creator OS Type  -> must be  **????**.